# Prevent control from inheriting it's parents disabled state

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I know it seems like an odd request but I have this layout. With it I'm very much enjoying and taking advantages of the FlowLayoutPanel. I disable it to disable all child controls. But there are cases I have a link in there I want enabled all the time. Is this possible?

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Enabled = false; // disable panel and all child controls
linkLabel1.Enabled = true; // re-enable somehow the link that was disabled inherently
```

I'm only asking because there maybe a way to do this, but if it's officially a bad design case then I will rethink my solution.

Previously to get around this I overlayed the control I want to enable/disable independently of the parent control. I would line it up and position the control so it appeared to be with the group. I hated this. It makes design difficult as drag and drop just puts it back into the container and also totally defeats the purpose of using a FlowLayoutPanel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foreach control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Where(x => x != linkLabel1)) control.Enabled = false`

Comment: Awesome, this is totally viable. Wrap this in an extension method and go! I'll provide a solution with an example of how I'm using this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion from Anthony. I've managed the following code that solves my dilemma. Using LINQ! (I always forget about using LINQ) I adjusted a bit with the extension methods and ability to just hammer in controls through a parameter array of what I do not want disabled. Very flexible to say the least.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "reset"
    flowLayoutPanel1.EnableAll();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // disable but the provide controls
    flowLayoutPanel1.DisableBut(checkBox1);
}

public static class Extensions
{

    public static void EnableAll(this FlowLayoutPanel container)
    {
        foreach (Control control in container.Controls.OfType<Control>())
            control.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void DisableBut(this FlowLayoutPanel container, params Control[] but)
    {
        foreach (Control control in (container.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x => (!but.Contains(x)))))
        {
            control.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

With suggested tweaks for performance, extensibility, etc.

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static void EnabledBut(this Control container, Boolean enabled, params Control[] but)
    {
        foreach (Control control in (container.Controls.OfType<Control>().Except(but)))
            control.Enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to make the extension methods more ... extensible... consider making the `container` parameter just a `Control` because any `Control` can have a list of child controls. Also, consider passing in the `enabled` state via another parameter so you can toggle both `Enabled = true` and `Enabled = false` conditions via the same extension methods.

Comment: You can simplify your "in" statement using [`.Execpt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) to `Control control in (container.Controls.OfType<Control>().Except(but))`, it should perform faster too.

Comment: I like that a lot @ScottChamberlain, it's also a lot more clear when read in all honest opinion. Thank you!